# Web applications and BerkeleyDB JE

Tags: web-applications, berkeley-db

I want to create a web application with database access.

Since I'm already familiar with using BerkeleyDB JE in java applications, I'd like to use it here as well. However I have problems to find Documentation on how BerkeleyDB can be integrated into a web-application.

I managed to run it IN-MEMORY, but this not really what I want. But is there an alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered Sqlite?
https://www.sqlite.org/